# Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined (protractor)

Tags: angularjs, protractor

```
       //get count of checked checkboxes, 
//count must be 1 because it selected one product
                    var checkedCount = productPage.selectedProducts.count();
                    expect(checkedCount).toBe(1).then(function () {
                        browser.sleep(2222);
                        productDialogPage. createTaskButton.click();
                    });
```

this is my code. When user selects, createtaskbutton gets active.

normally it is disabled.

error is

> Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>     Stack:
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

when i change to this

```
//get count of checked checkboxes, count must 1 be because it selected one product
                var checkedCount = productPage.selectedProducts.count();
                expect(checkedCount).toBe(1);
                browser.sleep(4222);


                //click task create and expect confirm dialog to be displyed
                productDialogPage.createTaskButton.click();



same
```

> Message:
>       Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
>     Stack:
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

it doesnot read my spec class, it goes another spec as soon as it enters.

also for this same

```
            //get count of checked checkboxes, count must 1 be because it selected one product
            var checkedCount = productPage.selectedProducts.count();
            expect(checkedCount).toBe(1);
            browser.sleep(4222);



            browser.wait(function() {
                return productDialogPage.createTaskButton.isPresent();
            })
```

Comment: How do you get the element createTaskButton ?

Answer (score 2):

1. `expect(actual).toBe(expected)` is not thenable because it does not return a promise.
2. It appears that you should try [`ExpectedConditions`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

---

```
var EC = ExpectedConditions;

//get count of checked checkboxes, 
//count must be 1 because it selected one product
var checkedCount = productPage.selectedProducts.count();
expect(checkedCount).toBe(1);

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(productDialogPage.createTaskButton, 4222));

//click task create and expect confirm dialog to be displyed
productDialogPage.createTaskButton.click();
```

Comment: but when i select product here
              `var checkedCount = productPage.selectedProducts.count();
               expect(checkedCount).toBe(1);`

it is enabled. no need clickable?

Comment: From your post you said that createTaskButton was disabled, so you should wait for createTaskButton to be clickable. Either that or your createTaskButton is not an actual element.

Comment: i changed yours because it gave error 
protractor.ExpectedConditions;
but still got error
:
 ` Failed: Cannot read property 'isPresent' of undefined
 Stack:
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPresent' of undefined `

despite i dont have ispresent. error line is 
`browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(productDialogPage.createTaskButton, 4222));`

Comment: Maybe it will also help to know how you are defining "createTaskButton". It sounds like it does not exist on your productDialogPage object.

Comment: @pronto is this the problem you have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909682/failed-cannot-read-property-ispresent-of-undefined/40939379#40939379

Answer (score 0):

For me ExpectedConditions (http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable) helped, see answer before. And you have to resolve the promises. Hope it helps! :-)

```
productPage.selectedProducts.count().then(function(countOfSelectedProducts) {
            expect(countOfSelectedProducts).toBe(1);
            });
        });

// and then wait till your TaskButton is enabled via ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable 

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(productDialogPage.element.createTaskButton()), 10000).then(function() {
        productDialogPage.element.createTaskButton.click();
});
```