# "Failed: Cannot read property 'isPresent' of undefined"

Tags: protractor

```
it('should be able to create a task for a product as a CTA', function () {
  browser.sleep(6222);browser.sleep(6222);console.log("ss");
  productPage.productsTab.click();
  expect(productPage.myProductsTab.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

  //select checkbox
  productPage.selectProduct.click();
  browser.sleep(2222);
  var elm = productDialogPage.createTaskButton;

  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  //get count of checked checkboxes, count must 1 be because it selected one product
  var checkedCount = productPage.selectedProducts.count();
  expect(checkedCount).toBe(1);
  browser.sleep(2222);

  browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm, 6222));

  //click task create and expect confirm dialog to be displyed
  productDialogPage.createTaskButton.click();
  expect(ProductDialogPage.confirmDialog.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
  browser.sleep(2222);

  //click yes to confirm creating task and expext dialog to displayed
  productDialogPage.yesBtnForConfirmDialog.click();
  //expect(taskPageObject.taskDialog.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
  browser.sleep(6222);

  //put input areas to task create dialog
  this.createTask();
  browser.sleep(2222);
```

this is my test

```
var elm = productDialogPage.createTaskButton;

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

//get count of checked checkboxes, count must 1 be because it selected one product
var checkedCount = productPage.selectedProducts.count();
expect(checkedCount).toBe(1);
browser.sleep(2222);

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm, 6222));

//click task create and expect confirm dialog to be displyed
productDialogPage.createTaskButton.click();
expect(ProductDialogPage.confirmDialog.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
browser.sleep(2222);
```

here the part

after count is 1, it means i selected only one product (md-checbox), it means product is selected so that button is active now. Before it was disabled

```
 disabled="disabled"
```

it has that. when i select, this is gone.

But as soon as it enters my test or my class page, it gives error. it does not run code because it does not wait.

it gives failure.

i used isvisible ispresentof but still same

error is for this code, "Failed: Cannot read property 'isPresent' of undefined"

but i dont have ispresent

before i had 2 classes only, now i separated classes according to dialog and tabs, this error started now.

i can see "ss" as output but

```
browser.sleep(6222);console.log("ss");
```

there is sleeping 6 seconds. İt does not go there. it checks i think all variables before.

**UPDATE**

ınstead productdialog.confirmdialog

i put real value

```
element.all(by.buttonText('Görev Oluştur')).first()element.all(by.buttonText('Görev Oluştur')).first()
```

and it works.

Why?

it was here, still here but no usage now

```
var ProductDialogPage = function () {
  //confirm dialog for task creating, use with isDisplayed
  this.confirmDialog = element.all(by.css('._md.md-default-theme._md-transition-in')).first();

  this.yesBtnForConfirmDialog = element.all(by.buttonText('Evet')).first();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

*There is no `createTaskButton` field defined in your `productDialogPage` page object.*

#### More information

You are getting this kind of error because the [`elementToBeClickable` expected condition](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/7d481d6886b39cb476b889de5d14186bda6dc066/lib/expectedConditions.ts#L190) function checks if an element is *visible, present and enabled* calling `isPresent()` and `isEnabled()` on an element. This is [related code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/7d481d6886b39cb476b889de5d14186bda6dc066/lib/expectedConditions.ts#L353) where the error is eventually thrown:

```
presenceOf(elementFinder: ElementFinder): Function {
  return elementFinder.isPresent.bind(elementFinder);
};
```

You are passing `elm` variable to the expected condition:

```
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm, 6222));
```

where `elm` is defined as:

```
var elm = productDialogPage.createTaskButton;
```

And, judging by the symptoms, `elm` gets an `undefined` value which means that there is no `createTaskButton` field in the `productDialogPage` Page Object.

Comment: what if my element is inside a different pageObject class, for example
`code` await commonPage.waitForElementVisible(saveReportsConfigurationButtonElement);
`code`
where saveReportsConfigurationButtonElement doest not exist inside commonPage?