# Protractor - Check if a radio-button is checked or not

Tags: selenium, protractor, mocha.js, chai

So I have this problem where I run a protractor/selenium test and sometimes a radio-button is already checked during the test and sometimes its not.

etc:

```
<div id="TRUCK" class="radio-item checked" data-gtm="truck">
```

or

```
<div id="TRUCK" class="radio-item" data-gtm="deliveryOpt-truck">
```

where you can see the class sometimes have the "checked" init and sometimes not.

What I am trying to do solve is that I want to make a function that clicks IF the radio-button is not checked and if its already checked then we just continue.

What I managed to do is:

```
it('Clicking Truck button', function (done) {

    browser.driver
        .then(() => browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id("TRUCK")))), 30000, "Timed out button")
        .then(() => browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element(by.id("TRUCK")).getWebElement()))
        .then(() => done());
```

however the problem is that it will uncheck it if the radio-button is already checked which is not good. So again.

I am trying to make a function that clicks. If the radio-button is not checked then we click. If its already checked then we continue.

How am I able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were close. To identify an element when the *class* attribute doesn't contain the value **checked** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  //div[@id='TRUCK' and not(contains(@class,'checked'))]
  ```
- *css*:

  ```
  div#TRUCK:not(.checked)
  ```

---

Effectively, if your use case is to invoke `click()` when the *class* attribute is not having the value **checked**, instead of `presenceOf()` you need to use the *ExpectedConditions* [`elementToBeClickable()`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable) and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- [xpath](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath):

  ```
  it('Clicking Truck button', function (done) {

      browser.driver
      .then(() => browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.xpath("//div[@id='TRUCK' and not(contains(@class,'checked'))]")))), 30000, "Timed out button")
  ```
- [css](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css):

  ```
  it('Clicking Truck button', function (done) {

      browser.driver
      .then(() => browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.css("div#TRUCK:not(.checked)")))), 30000, "Timed out button")
  ```

Comment: Oh right! That is true. However now the problem is that I would get a "failed" in the test due to it is already clickable right? Is there a way to mark it as a "GOOD" if its already checked and vice versa if we need to click?

Comment: 1) Clicking Truck button <--- Failed |
 √ Clicking Truck button <--- Success

Comment: This line of code will **fail**, incase the element html _class_ attribute contains `checked`, else this line will **pass**.

Comment: Yeah exactly. If its already checked then it will fail. I mean it seems to work as I wish but I was thinking maybe it would look more beautiful if it pass if the element is checked or to be checked. Fail only if etc. element is not found or button disabled?

Comment: @Thrillofit86 Great News !!! Glad to be able to help you out !!! That logic is specific to protractor and I don't practice protractor that often :) I'm with pure webdriver through Java/Python.

Comment: Ahh! Alright seems right! However I did get a issue though. Im not sure if its actually now working or not. The error I do get when its checked is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPresent' of undefined` seems like it shouldn't return that?

Comment: @Thrillofit86 You are getting it from the next line of code pertaining to `getWebElement()` as `click()` doesn't returns anything and is considered as **undefined** / **NULL**

Comment: Ahhhhhh... Make sense now. So maybe if I could somehow a if statement or a assert from Chai https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/ that checks basically if its true then we skip the click or something like that? I think... but either way since your knowledge is not on protractor and yet helped me I still consider this as the answer but would appreciate maybe if you have any ideas what to do if you check the Chai documentation :D Because I am still abit lost of ideas

Comment: Done! Thank you! I will continue to see if there is a way to make a sort of if-else statement for this. :)

Comment: By the way. I tried to change to `.then(() => browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.xpath("//div[@id='TRUCK']")))), 30000, "Timed out button")` and it still says the error about `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isPresent' of undefined` It shouldn't do that? I removed the click function aswell so its only the same as your answer.

Comment: @Thrillofit86 Did you declare `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;`? See: [“Failed: Cannot read property 'isPresent' of undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909682/failed-cannot-read-property-ispresent-of-undefined)

Comment: Oh yeah. I do have it at the beginning of the code so it does triggers it. I believe thats the reason I do get a TypeError I believe otherwise I dont think I would get any message.

Comment: Ahhh stupid me! I realized I did a mistake in another class... No wonder why I do get that problem. My fault!!

Answer (score 0):

This will check if checkbox is selected and if not will select it:

```
static async selectCheckbox(element: ElementFinder, markChecked: boolean) {
        const isSelected = await elementt.isSelected();
        if (isSelected !== markChecked) {
            await elementt.click();
        }
        return;
    }
```