# How to extract partial text information from a label tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to loop through different checkboxes and check them if the text is present in the list then click if not then move on.

the html element that I have been able to extract is below:

```
<label>
 <input type ="checkbox" value = "pf29">
 <span> BNN Bloomberg </span>
 <span> class='count'>(16)</span>
<label>
```

when I do element.text it gives me BNN Bloomberg (16). Is there a way to restrict the text output to only BNN Bloomberg?

There are roughly 33 different tags so I cant use any of the string methods to limit the number of characters.

Fairly new to html and selenium so excuse my wording.

Currently this is what my code looks like

```
element_list = (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='modal-dialog-padded-body'] label"))
source = element_list[3].text
print(source)
```

print(source) gives me BNN Bloomberg (16)

Edit: I have to loop through 21 different elements and look at the text to see what the source is and check the checkbox accordingly.

Comment: Please provide some code?

Comment: Edited the question with my current execution

Answer (score 1):

You can try either of the following css selector.

```
element_list =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='modal-dialog-padded-body'] label>span:nth-of-type(1)")
source = element_list[3].text
print(source)
```

OR

```
element_list =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='modal-dialog-padded-body'] label>span:not(.count)")
source = element_list[3].text
print(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close enough.
To retrieve the text **BNN Bloomberg** you need to traverse one step deeper till the first `<span>` tag and youyou can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.modal-dialog-padded-body label span:not(.count)").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal-dialog-padded-body']//label//span[not(contains(@class,'count'))]").text)
  ```

---

### Best practices

To print the first *title* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the`visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute::

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-dialog-padded-body label span:not(.count)"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-dialog-padded-body']//label//span[not(contains(@class,'count'))]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Protractor - Check if a radio-button is checked or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184694/protractor-check-if-a-radio-button-is-checked-or-not/60184892#60184892)

Comment: @soom Yes, you can. I will update the answer in a short while.